# How to connect a Laravel Sail instance with an SSH tunnel?

Tags: laravel, ssh, port, ssh-tunnel, laravel-sail

I have a Laravel app which needs to connect to a secure external API with very strict access requirements. There is a handler hosted on AWS which has a bunch of signed certificates etc. The only way to connect to that API is via that specific server due to those requirements.

Now, to test things on my local machine, I do the following:

1. SSH to the server using the -D flag to set up a SOCKS proxy.
2. Use [this socks to http package](https://github.com/oyyd/http-proxy-to-socks) to convert the proxy.
3. Set up Postman's proxy settings to use that http proxy.

That all works fine and I can complete the requests as expected.

However, I'd like to be able to use the proxy in my local Laravel environment too, for which I use Sail.

The problem is that I'm unsure of how to get the container to interact with the proxy. Using the method above in my local machine, I can cURL the required endpoint just fine, but if I try to do it via the container itself, it refuses to connect.

Any help would be appreciated!